# How to reshape or transpose a dataset by considering selected columns and rows in a large dataset (World Bank example)

Tags: python, pandas, reshape, transpose, data-wrangling

I am trying to wrangle a dataset from the World Bank website and I need to reshape in a way for the series name to be the first row and the years to be all structured along a column. There are 50 years and over 100 indicators in the dataset so this reshape needs some form of automatisation to work for me. An extract of the actual dataset looks like the following image below.

[image]

In order to ease the process of reshaping I am also sharing a reproducible code to show the transition I have in mind in terms of the arrangement between columns and rows as illustrated in narrative form so far.

**Please note**:The reproducible code is not a perfect representation of the output since it is very much simplified and the actual dataset at play has hundreds of indicators and hundreds of countries

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Country':  ['Argentina', 'Argentina', 'Albania','Albania','Cuba','Cuba'],
        'Series': ['Indicator 1', 'Indicator 2', 'Indicator 1', 'Indicator 2','Indicator 1', 'Indicator 2', ],
        '2014': [1, 2, 3,4,5,6],
        '2015': [2, 4, 1,2,3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Country','Series','2014','2015'])
df
```

[image]

And I would like to use a snippet to reach this structure, shown in the output below the code

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Country':  ['Argentina', 'Argentina', 'Albania','Albania','Cuba','Cuba'],
        'Year': [2014,2015,2014,2015,2014,2015],
        'Indicator 1': [1, 2,3,1,5,3],
        'Indicator 2': [2,4,4,2,6,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Country','Year','Indicator 1','Indicator 2'])
df
```

[image]

I am looking for a quick snippet to reach my result without too much time consuming column by column solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['Country','Series'])
         .stack()
         .unstack(1)
         .rename_axis(columns=None, index=('Country','Year'))
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
     Country  Year  Indicator 1  Indicator 2
0    Albania  2014            3            4
1    Albania  2015            1            2
2  Argentina  2014            1            2
3  Argentina  2015            2            4
4       Cuba  2014            5            6
5       Cuba  2015            3            4
```

If not working because duplicates use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) (possible duplicates are aggregated by `mean`):

```
df1 = (df.melt(['Country','Series'], var_name='Year')
         .pivot_table(index=['Country','Year'], 
                      columns='Series', 
                      values='value',
                      aggfunc='mean')
         .rename_axis(columns=None, index=('Country','Year'))
         .reset_index()
         )
print (df1)
     Country  Year  Indicator 1  Indicator 2
0    Albania  2014            3            4
1    Albania  2015            1            2
2  Argentina  2014            1            2
3  Argentina  2015            2            4
4       Cuba  2014            5            6
5       Cuba  2015            3            4
```